# jQuery click handler not firing for all elements

Tags: jquery, ajax, click

I need to create a number of buttons based on JSON returned from a php (in which I'm using MySQL to get that info from the database). The code below works by creating the buttons I need, but for some reason, the click handler is only called when I click on the first button in the list. Any ideas why the handler does not fire for all buttons and how I can fix it?

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$.ajax({ url: "file.php", data: "id=1", dataType: "json", type: "post",
  success: function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(index, element) {
      var classBtns="";
      $.each(return_array(element.date), function(i, d) {
        class_button = "<span class='button' id='classBtn' data-date='"+d+"' data-time='"+element.time+"'>Press</span>";
        classBtns += "<p class='goingDates'>"+d+class_button+"</p>";
      });
      $('div').append(classBtns);
    });

    $("#classBtn").on("click", function() {
      alert("clicked "+$(this).data('date'));
    });
  }
});
});
```

Also, is passing data through $(this).data the best way to get the data I need into the click handler? I'd prefer for it not to be visible in the HTML if possible, but I can't figure out another why to have that data accessible to the handler. If I put the click handler inside any of the $.each statements, then the alert is called multiple times when a button is clicked.

Comment: It's because you are using ID selector instead of CLASS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First `ID` in a HTML page are **supposed to be unique.**

Next you would need to **delegate the events** for **Dynamically created elements** for the click events to work

If there are multiple elements with the same `ID`

This selector `$('#classBtn')` will only fetch the first instance no matter how many elements with that ID are available.

Use `class instead..`

I see you already have class defined for the element. So get rid of the `ID`

And change this piece of code

```
 $("#classBtn").on("click", function() {
```

to

```
 $(document).on("click", ".button" function() {
```

For better performance you can delegate the events to a `static Ancestor` of the elements instead of the `document`.

The way you are binding the events, they may be bound multiple times to the same element. So move that piece of code to outside the Ajax request

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $.ajax({
        url: "file.php",
        data: "id=1",
        dataType: "json",
        type: "post",
        success: function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (index, element) {
                var classBtns = "";
                $.each(return_array(element.date), function (i, d) {
                    class_button = "<span class='button' id='classBtn' data-date='" + d + "' data-time='" + element.time + "'>Press</span>";
                    classBtns += "<p class='goingDates'>" + d + class_button + "</p>";
                });
                $('div').append(classBtns);
            });
        }
    });

     $(document).on("click", ".button" function() {
        alert("clicked " + $(this).data('date'));
    });
});
```

Comment: Good catch. I didn't notice that delegation thing at first. This is the accepted answer, in my opinion. Not mine. :-)

Comment: He's binding the click handler after adding the dynamic elements, not when the DOM is loaded, so delegation isn't really necessary.

Comment: aahh right.. Did not observe that .. Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 0):

IDs like "#classBtn" are meant to be unique, and so JQuery will only use the first instance it finds. Use a class insteads (such as ".classBtn").

Answer (score 0):

Use class="classBtn" instead of id="classBtn". $(this).data would work fine also.